# SyntaxError: invalid syntax Why?

Tags: python

Ok this is weird...
I'm trying to accomplish the following:
if i have lost up to 2 times then bet = startingbet
but if I have lost more than 2 times maximum of (5 times lost) 
then bet = bet * 2
if more than 5 times lost then bet = startingbet

```
                if losttwice <= 2:
                    bet = startingbet
                elif losttwice <= 5:
                    bet = bet * 2
                else:
                    bet = startingbet
```

also if possible can anyone help me to add one more thing to this. I would like to do a random 50% chance when losttwice <= 2 (when I lost 1-2 times) for it to be bet = startingbet or bet = bet * 2 based on 50% chance

Thanks a lot!

The error:

```
  File "scripy.py", line 153
    elif losttwice <= 5:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Post the whole traceback, your code looks fine syntax wise.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary what you mean by traceback?   `File "scripy.py", line 153
    elif (losttwice <= 5):
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: There is no syntax error here. You'll need to show us the text of the error you get (the traceback) and the portion of the code which actually caused the syntax error.

Comment: Indent issue?  an `elif` without an `if`?

Comment: @Mark that syntax error shouldn't be happening. Is the line before it **exactly** the same as the code you've posted?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary looks like OP's problem was tabs versus spaces, can you revert your edit to leave them in? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing tabs and spaces. One tab is equivalent to eight spaces, so your code really looks like this to the interpreter (solid lines are tabs, dotted lines are spaces):

[image]

You have to keep your indentation consistent. Use *just* tabs or *just* spaces. [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) recommends four spaces, which is what most projects use.

Comment: I always have issues with this how can I avoid those issues? Should I use python editor?

Comment: it seems like `if 2 <= losttwicew <= 5: bet = bet * 2 else: bet = startingbet` would be clearer.

Comment: @Mark Set your text editor to insert spaces instead of tabs. If you don't know how, search it...

Comment: @2rs2ts: And if your editor doesn't have the option, use another editor!

Comment: @blender thanks for the help it worked! any chance I can get some help how to add the option for 50% chance? It will be great :)

Comment: @Mark: Please, open another question if you want to change subject. The fact that it uses the same code than this one is not useful. After all, asking in SO is free!

Comment: @blender what program did you use to check this?

Comment: @Mark: Sublime Text 2. You have to enable "show whitespace" in the settings file.